# Streaming list of dictionaries in Python with asyncio

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

I am working on Python server/client application where the server receives some data from the client and based on this data it collects a list of dictionaries from an embedded k/v store and streams it back.
I put here a code that reproduces the error. There is a reason why I put everything into separate functions on server side (clients send different requests).

The problem is that the server sends faster than the client can consume and the client reads several responses at a time, sometimes it is just a part of the message which has been truncated. I thought writelines/readline pair will read from the socket appropriately, but I think I missed something. write/drain also overloads the socket and once multiple results are read the client failes because chunked serialized dictionary is read to orjson.loads.

What is the proper way to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Server:

```
import orjson

async def getResult(cnt : int):
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    result = []
    for i in range(cnt):
        result.append({"key" : i})
    return result

async def send(writer, list_of_dict):
    for r in list_of_dict:
        print(f"\nSending: {r}")
        writer.writelines([orjson.dumps(r)])
        await writer.drain()
    # sending END signal
    writer.writelines([orjson.dumps("END")])
    await writer.drain()

async def handleClient(reader, writer):
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print(f"Connection from {addr}")
    data = await reader.readline()
    message = orjson.loads(data)
    print(f"Received {message} from {addr}")
    counter = message["send_me"]
    responses = await getResult(counter)
    await send(writer, responses)
    print("Close the client socket")
    writer.close()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(handleClient, '127.0.0.1', 4000, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

# Serve requests until Ctrl+C is pressed
print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
 
# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

Client

```
import asyncio
import orjson
 
async def async_client(loop):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 4000, loop=loop)
    counter = 5
    print(f"Request counter: {counter}")
    # in real life the message is a complex dictionary
    msg = {"send_me" : counter}
    writer.writelines([orjson.dumps(msg)])
    #without write_eof the server reader.readline() waits for data and blocks
    if writer.can_write_eof():
        writer.write_eof()

    while True:
        data = await reader.readline()
        if data:
            print(data)
            r = orjson.loads(data)
            print(f"Received: {r}")
            if r == "END":
                print("server completed")
                break
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    print('Close the socket')
    writer.close()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(async_client(loop))
loop.close()
```

Error:

```
>python echo_client.py
Request counter: 5

b'{"key":0}{"key":1}{"key":2}{"key":3}{"key":4}"END"'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "echo_client.py", line 32, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(async_client(loop))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "echo_client.py", line 21, in async_client
    r = orjson.loads(data)

orjson.JSONDecodeError: trailing characters at line 1 column 10: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is much simpler: `writelines` doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't insert newline characters, it just writes any data you give it. This is why the `readline()` by your client picks up the payload and `"END"` concatenated together. This is also why you need `write_eof` in the other direction.

If you want to write a line, then just write a newline character (byte) after your payload. You can abstract that in a function that handles it for you:

```
async def write_msg(writer, msg):
    writer.write(orjson.dumps(msg))
    writer.write('\n')
    await writer.drain()

async def read_msg(reader):
    line = await reader.readline()
    return orjson.loads(line)
```

You can use these on both the client and the server to communicate.

On an aside note, you should probably switch to the newer `asyncio.run()` API which creates and correctly tears down the event loop with a single async entry point. Your server setup would look like this:

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.start_server(handleClient, '127.0.0.1', 4000)
    await server.wait_closed()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me! 
writelines([orjson.dumps(msg), b"\n"]) # 1 line + binary new line

Comment: @spyder That works too. I'd completely avoid the `writelines` method, as it's just incredibly confusing (it should have been called `write_sequence` or something). And since stream writes are buffered, having two calls to `write` should be no slower than a single one.